# How do I put saved searches or smart groups as menu options in WordPress?

Tags: custom-fields, smartgroups, custom-search

Is it possible to make custom searches (smart groups) available from the custom menu. For instance, I am tracking elections (organizations) with custom fields for special elections, open races, candidates by district etc. Would like to make it easy to search from the menu for all open races, all members of the U.S. Senate etc. Is the only way to put custom searches on the menu to learn .php and create a custom search page on the backend?

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU6EU.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU6EU.png)

Answer (score 2):

You could generate report using the Smart Group as your filter and save that report.  The report can be used as a dashlet which is available upon login or you can have it emailed to you as well.  More dashlet info is here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/reports/

Comment: thank you. i will try this.